# Insert row if duplicate exists for certain date VBA

Tags: vba, loops, duplicates

I'm wondering how to write a code in VBA for the following process. 
Loop through a spreadsheet with lots of data
If the Name matches and the Date matches then write the information A B C
If there is more than one match for Name and Date then write information A B C in the next row and continue to loop through the information.

Basically if there is more than one information for the same name and date then add a new row with that information

Better explained as: If a certain instance of names and dates has more than one record (info) associated with it, it'll print both of these before continuing on with the next pair of Names/Dates

[What the display should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpLKR.png)

Answer (score 0):

"If the Name matches and the Date matches then write the information A B C"

Matches what? information A B C meaning what? info?

I think what you're trying to say is:

If a certain instance of names and dates has more than one record (info) associated with it, it'll print both of these before continuing on with the next pair of Names/Dates?...

You really need to clarify what you're asking.